# Java Fill nested HashMap

Tags: java

I have a problem. I created the following object:

```java
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Slope>>>>
     usedSlopeList = new HashMap<>();
```

Then I have the following `ArrayList<Slope>`:

```java
ArrayList<Slope> tempSlopeList = Slope.getSlopeList(
    agent, key, slope, startDateTimeWithExtraCandles);
```

But when I want to fill the `usedSlopeList` like this:

```java
usedSlopeList.put("15m", 
new HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Slope>>>()
    .put("EMA15", new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Slope>>()
    .put(15, tempSlopeList)));
```

Unfortunately this gives me the error:

```
Required type: HashMap<Integer,java.util.ArrayList<com.company.models.Slope>>
Provided: ArrayList<Slope,
```

But I don't see why this is wrong...
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map::put` returns **value** while a map is expected.

That is, `new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Slope>>().put(15, tempSlopeList)` returns `ArrayList<Slope>` and so on.

The following code using `Map.of` available since Java 9 works fine:

```java
usedSlopeList.put("15m", new HashMap<>(Map.of("EMA15", new HashMap<>(Map.of(15, tempSlopeList)))));
```

---

**Update**
A cleaner solution not requiring Java 9 could be to implement a generic helper method which creates an instance of a `HashMap` and populates it with the given key/value:

```java
static <K, V> HashMap<K, V> fillMap(K key, V val) {
    HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(key, val);
    return map;
}

ArrayList<Slope> tempSlopeList = new ArrayList<>(Collections.emptyList());
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Slope>>>>
     usedSlopeList2 = fillMap("15m", 
                          fillMap("EMA15", 
                              fillMap(15, tempSlopeList)
                          )
                      );
    
System.out.println(usedSlopeList2);
```

Output:

```
{15m={EMA15={15=[]}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, very easy solution for me!

Answer (score 1):

You used the new HashMap().put() as the second parameter in your code, which causes the issue.

[HashMap().put](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,V)) is not a builder method; it doesn't return the hashmap. It returns the previous value associated with the key, which in your case is an ArrayList.

Comment: Then what could I use to create a filled hashmap?

Comment: If you don't have an other map with the values then you can't inline them. You have to create a new variable and fill them up manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have a map, which expects a string as key and a hashmap as value, but put() method doesn't return a hashmap, it return an V object(<K, V>), that is why you should create hashmap separately, add the object and than try to add it.
Anyway i think you should reconsider your design.